# Конвертация изображения в код

Tags: python, pillow, minecraft

Здраствуйте ,пишу программу для конвертации 3d моделей в код для постройки mc (библиотека майнкрафта основанная на python).Для удобства разбиваю 3d модель в изображение

[image: Пример изображение]

Всё что белое нужно переводить в код , черное пропускается .
Т.к. это 3d модель таких изображений может быть от 10 до 150 штук +- (количество уровней)

В чем заключается проблема: Мне нужно найти оптимальный способ строить через библиотеку mc .Там есть прекрасная функция setCuboid , функция принимает 6 параметров (7 , но в данном случае он не важен) x,y,z и x1,y1,z1 .  x,y,z начальные координаты , x1,y1,z1 конечные .

Строительство по слайсам ,занимает очень много времени . Как я это делал брал точку (1) и искал ей конец вдоль какой либо координаты (2), заполнял ,получалось что-то вроде этого setCuboid(0,0,0,10,0,0). Но это достаточно медленный процесс, особенно когда таких "слайсов" около 150 штук.

[image: Пример поиска координат]

**СУТЬ**
Нужно построить за минимальное время . Для этого я сохранял всё изображения в массив[номер_изображения(он же "y")][x][z]. После пробовал найти быстрый способ через перебор, как это работает у меня. `if allpoints[y][x][z] == "1":` программа находит пиксель белого цвета,далее добавляет значение 1 к каждой координате и если они тоже белые добавляет ещё и т.д.

`for plus in range(300):`

```
`if allpoint[y+plus][x+plus][y+plus] == "1":`
```

eсли значение равно 0 программа сохраняет в файл такой вывод: setCuboid(x,y,z,x+plus,y+plus,z+plus)

но даже если строить таким способом одиночные пиксели увеличивают количество строк или вовсе пропускают блоки(пиксели)

Comment: Не совсем понял. Если у вас каждый слайс - черно-белая картинка, что мешает сразу преобразовать ее в двумерный массив, например, с помощью numpy? а потом весь набор слайсов - в трехмерный массив с помощью той же бибилиотеки?

Comment: Я и так храню всё в массиве. Вопрос в другом, как за наименьшее количество пере образований построить.Мне за раз нужно строить максимальное количество блоков (включить в переобразование максимально много пикселей со всех слоёв) . Как пример у меня всё изображение белое, по сути я могу построить за одно действия, выбрать края низа и верха и готово. Только как это реализовать?)

Comment: Еще раз. речь шла о массивах numpy. вы можете сразу преобразовать черно-белую картинку в 2м-массив одним методом.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеки PIL и numpy:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("WGadg.png") # имя вашего файла со слайсом
img.load()
slc = np.asarray(img.convert('1'), dtype="int32" )
```

теперь у вас в slc двумерный массив numpy со значением 0, если точка черная (пустая) и 1, если точка белая. соответственно, к каждой точке можно обратиться по индексу:

```
print(slc[0][0])
print(slc[10][10])
```

```
0
1
```